# Server creates shortcuts in Shared Drive automatically when file is opened

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, shared-storage

We have just setup a Windows 2012 R2 Server with shared drives. We have on particular user who has an issue that whenever they open a file it creates a shortcut on the root of that mapped drive.

I have copied another users profile whom this isn't happening to and given him that account and wiped the machine incase it was setup incorrectly however it keeps creating shortcuts of everything he opens.

Googling this problem only shows "How to map a drive".

Thanks